# Convert HTML to docx - Apache POI Java

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

Does anyone know how to convert an html document to a docx using Apache POI, bringing across styles, font sizes, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache POI in java doesn't help you in converting html document to docx instead it can only help you in creating a docx file.

> In short POI helps in creation and not in transformation.